# MySQL Update Join returns #1205 - Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to execute the following query but it returns `#1205 - Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction`.

Query

```
UPDATE cities c JOIN tmp_cities t ON (c.name = t.cityName) 
SET c.latitude = t.latitude
  , c.longitude = t.longitude 
WHERE c.latitude = 0 AND c.longitude = 0
```

Also, it's not affecting any of the row. In other words, this query totally fails to execute in my phpMyAdmin. What can be the solution?

Comment: `#1205 - Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction.` is caused when another process is currently inserting, updating or deleting from a table in your query. Is this being ran against an active database?

Comment: And what is meant by active database here? By the way, I have "KILLed" the currently running process multiple times but it is still not working.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have locked `cities` or `tmp_cities` elsewhere for a long time. Possible situations:

1. There is another query that locks `cities` or `tmp_cities` but has not been completed yet.
2. You lock `cities` or `tmp_cities` but never unlock it

Start by executing the below query to find which records/tables are locked:

```
SELECT * from performance_schema.data_locks;
```